# Is there a way to get the raw data from a DVI port?

Tags: c#, .net, screen-scraping, hardware-interface, dvi

I have nopt seeing anyone else trying to do this. It is completely possible I am apperoaching this the wrong way. Basically, I have a computer with a DVI input. If nothing is attached to the DVI input, then a program on the computer loads some images on screen. If an output source is connected to the DVI port, then my program should stop writing images and use the DVI video feed instead.

What mechanisms exist to determine if a DVI input exists, and if there is currently a valid video signal present? How can I read the video stream?

Or am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Comment: Can you clarify this? I am slightly confused when you say you "have a computer with a dvi INPUT" then later say "If an OUTPUT source is connected to the DVI port ..." Are you talking about trying to determine if a monitor is connected to one of the DVI output ports on your video card?

Comment: Sorry for being ambiguous before. Basically, this is an embedded device that is either going to have an expansion card with a DVI input or a DVI input built into the motherboard.

I have a program that is generating images onto the screen area of this embedded computer, so that a screen capture program can take the images and upload them elsewhere. However, if someone plugs a computer into the DVI input on the controller, the images for the screen capture should come from that computer's DVI output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a hardware level most video input subsystems, analog or digital, are capable of detecting the presence of an input signal, or at least something that has a lot of the characteristics of one.

For a digital standard, you have actual clocking data either on its own wire, or encoded in a serial data stream.  If there appears to be a clock, and if its frequency is regular and reasonable would be a first test (though for some standards, reasonable can cover a huge range of frequencies).

Next, video (not just digital, even analog) has a repeating structure of lines and fields, so there should be two identifiable submultiples of the pixel clock, one corresponding to the start or end of each line, and the other to the start or end of each field (screen).  Again, these might have their own wires, might have unique means of encoding (special voltages in the analog case), or might represent time gaps in the pixel data.  Even if there were no sync and no retrace times, statistical analysis of the pixel data would probably give clues to the X and Y dimensions as many features in the picture would repeat.

Actual video input subsystems (think flatpanel monitor) can have even more complicated detection and auto-adapting circuits - they may for example resample the input in time to change the dots-per-line resolution, or they may even put it in a frame buffer and scale it in both X and Y.

What details of the inner workings of the video capture circuit are exposed to consumer, or even driver level software would depend a lot on the specifics of the chipset used - hopefully a data sheet is available.  It's pretty likely though that somewhere there is a readable register bit that indicates if the input is capturing something that the circuit "thinks" is a video signal.  You might even be able to read out parameters such as the X and Y resolution and scanning rates or pixel clock rate.

Similarly, the ability to get data out of the port would be chipset dependent, but if the port is going to be useful for anything, there is presumably an operating system driver for it which provides some sort of useful API to video consuming applications.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the exact hardware I will be using yet, so it is almost impossible to get any technical specifications or proprietary APIs. Do you know of any generic methods for reading the data from a display port, or should I just wait until I get more info. Right now, I am using WMI and hoping that can accomplish my needs

Comment: Any recommendations on cards that are "programmer friendly" so to speak? Preferably one with it's own API, but detailed technical specs are better than nothing.